# Parse email fields

Tags: python, email, parsing

I want to parse email addresses from a `To:` email field.

Indeed, when looping on the emails in a [mbox](https://docs.fileformat.com/email/mbox/):

```
mbox = mailbox.mbox('test.mbox')
for m in mbox:
  print m['To']
```

we can get things like:

```
info@test.org, Blahblah <blah@test.com>, <another@blah.org>, "Hey" <last@one.com>
```

That should be parsed into:

```
[{email: "info@test.org", name: ""}, 
 {email: "blah@test.com", name: "Blahblah"},
 {email: "another@blah.org", name: ""},
 {email: "last@one.com", name: "Hey"}]
```

Is there something already built-in (in `mailbox` or another module) for this or nothing?

*I read a few times [this doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.message.html#module-email.message) but I didn't find something relevant.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`email.utils.getaddresses()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.utils.html#email.utils.getaddresses) for this:

```
>>> getaddresses(['info@test.org, Blahblah <blah@test.com>, <another@blah.org>, "Hey" <last@one.com>'])
[('', 'info@test.org'), ('Blahblah', 'blah@test.com'), ('', 'another@blah.org'), ('Hey', 'last@one.com')]
```

(Note that the function expects a list, so you have to enclose the string in `[...]`.)

Answer (score 1):

**`email.parser` has the modules you're looking for**. `email.message` is still relevant, because the parser will return messages using this structure, so you'll be getting your header data from that. But to actually *read* the files in, `email.parser` is the way to go.

Comment: How does `email.parser` parse the content of the `To` header?

Answer (score 1):

As pointed by @TheSpooniest, `email` has a parser:

```
import email

s = 'info@test.org, Blahblah <blah@test.com>, <another@blah.org>, "Hey" <last@one.com>'

for em in s.split(','):
    print email.utils.parseaddr(em)
```

gives:

```
('', 'info@test.org')
('Blahblah', 'blah@test.com')
('', 'another@blah.org')
('Hey', 'last@one.com')
```

Comment: That doesn't work, when the name or email has a comma: `"Example, John" <foo,bar@example.com>`.

Answer (score 0):

Python provides **email.Header.decode_header()** for decoding header. The function decode each atom and return a list of tuples ( text, encoding ) that you still have to decode and join to get the full text.

For addresses, Python provides **email.utils.getaddresses()** that split addresses in a list of tuple ( display-name, address ). display-name need to be decoded too and addresses must match the RFC2822 syntax. The function **getmailaddresses()** does all the job.

Here's a tutorial that might help http://blog.magiksys.net/parsing-email-using-python-header